# PHP foreach cycle in separate divs

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

My PHP script's foreach cycle generates all blog articles information from database and then displays it in one place. I want each article information to be displayed in separate divs. How do I do it?

```
<div class="blog">
<?php if (count($articles)): foreach ($articles as $article): ?>
    <article><?php echo get_excerpt($article); ?><hr></article>
<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your div inside `foreach` block

```
<div class="blog">
  <?php if (count($articles)): foreach ($articles as $article): ?>
    <div>
        <article><?php echo get_excerpt($article); ?><hr></article>
    </div>
  <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="blog">
<?php if (count($articles)): foreach ($articles as $article): ?>
    <div><article><?php echo get_excerpt($article); ?><hr></article></div>
<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
</div>
```

Simply surrounds your articles with div's